# Tensorflow 2.4.0 Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow

My cuda is 11.0, and I have pip install this.

```
python install tensorflow==2.4.0
```

After input

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU')
cpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='CPU')
print(gpus, cpus)
```

got this

```
[] [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
2023-02-01 19:23:13.355591: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:af:00.0 name: A100-PCIE-40GB computeCapability: 8.0
coreClock: 1.41GHz coreCount: 108 deviceMemorySize: 39.59GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 1.41TiB/s
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357678: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357726: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357743: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357758: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357773: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357919: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357955: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357970: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2023-02-01 19:23:13.357978: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`python install tensorflow==2.4.0` is not the right code to install tensorflow.

You can install tensorflow using `pip` command or `conda` command (if you have installed conda software) in your system after installing python.

**To install tensorflow using `pip` or `conda` in conda environment.**

- Open the anaconda command prompt after installing anaconda/Miniconda in you system
- Create a conda VirEnv - `tf` and install tensorflow after activating the VirEnv

  `conda create --name tf python=3.9` 
  `conda activate tf` 
  `pip install --upgrade pip`

  `pip install tensorflow` #or
  `conda install tensorflow`

Please follow all the [software requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) to enable **Tensorflow GPU support** in your system and add them to bin directories to your [PATH](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#set_your_path).

- Then install the CUDA, cuDNN with conda and install tensorflow.

  `conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0`
  `pip install "tensorflow-gpu<2.11"` #TF 2.11 not supported for GPU setup

Now you can verify if you've installed TensorFlow successfully.

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='GPU')
cpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='CPU')
print(gpus, cpus)
```

**Note :** Please make sure you have installed the right CUDA and cuDNN compatible to the installed Python and TensorFlow version in your system as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).